# ¿Hay algún límite a la hora de concatenar vocales en un verso?

Tags: poesía

En otras preguntas se ha tratado el tema de la sinalefa. Sin embargo, de vez en cuando me topo con algún verso que concatena hasta tres palabras juntas en una misma sinalefa. El último ejemplo lo he encontrado en una canción de la película *Vaiana* (sí, esta es otra de mis preguntas basadas en las pelis que veo con mis hijos). En esta, el personaje de Tamatoa canta lo siguiente:

> Maui, tío,
>   lo puedes intentar,
>   pero nunca antes un semidiós
>   ganó a un decápodo.

Dejando de lado el hecho de que consiguen rimar *semidiós* con *decápodo* usando el ritmo de la canción (suena como *dekápodó*), ese último verso se pronuncia así:

> Ga-nóaun-de-cá-po-do

Vemos que se enlazan vocales de hasta tres palabras. La cuestión es ¿hay algún límite? ¿O podemos enlazar todos los sonidos vocálicos que queramos en una misma sinalefa?

Bonus: ¿cuáles son las sinalefas más largas que se hayan escrito en poesía o canciones?

Comment: Obviamente, hay un cierto límite en cuánto a número de palabras porque solo tenemos unas cuantas palabras que son puramente vocálicas que tendrían que ir en el medio.  Quizás alguien podría crear una frase con dos o más de estas, con una palabra que acabe en vocal antes de ellas y otra que termine en vocal después, pero lo veo difícil.  (sobre todo por pausas que haríamos naturalmente, si decimos, "va a u omitirlo o reescribirlo", esta *u* tendría una pausa breve entre ella y la *a*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como todo en poesía, va a depender mucho de la manera que tenga cada cual de pronunciar, y de las licencias que se tome el autor...

Lo más parecido a una fuente oficial que he encontrado, es [esto](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Diptongo-triptongo-hiato-sinalefa.htm):

> *«La posibilidad de la sinalefa con más de dos vocales depende de que éstas se hallen en serie de abertura creciente o decreciente, o de que las más abiertas estén en el centro de la sílaba como ápice silábico de ella: las más cerradas están en posición explosiva o implosiva, en la tensión o en la distensión, respectivamente.»* [Gili Gaya, Samuel: Elementos de fonética general. Madrid: Gredos, 1966, p. 117]
>
> *«La posibilidad de juntarse por sinalefa varias vocales españolas depende de que formen serie de abertura creciente (iea) o decreciente (aei); o de que las de articulación más cerrada se hallen en los extremos de la sílaba, y las más abiertas en el centro. Por ejemplo, en* salió a esperarlo *se juntan cuatro vocales, porque la articulación se abre progresivamente i-o-a, y luego se cierra en e. En la frase* esta o aquella *no pueden unirse las tres vocales porque la o es más cerrada que las dos aes en que está intercalada, y exige un nuevo impulso articulatorio, es decir, una sílaba distinta. Cabe, por lo tanto, definir en este sentido la sílaba como el conjunto de sonidos comprendidos entre dos depresiones de la articulación.»* [Gili Gaya, o. cit., p. 95-96]

De lo que se deduce, como digo, que va a depender de qué palabras sean y de como sean pronunciadas las vocales en cuestión (abriendo o cerrando más de lo habitual para conseguir el efecto...).